# I need create Switch from snapshot response in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to get the name of each item coming from snapshot.data!.sections![i].checklists! .map((e) => e.quesito and transform it into Text (' ') for each item, but I didn't find a solution at this moment and I can't get the title for my SwitchListTile...

```
ListView.builder(
                            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: 6,
                            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                              return Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    width: double.infinity,
                                    padding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                                    color: Colors.grey[200],
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          '${snapshot.data!.secoes![i].nome}',
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 16,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        const SizedBox(
                                          height: 30,
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  ...snapshot.data!.secoes![i].checklists!
                                      .map<Widget>(
                                    (e) => SwitchListTile(
                                      title: Text(''),
                                      value: true,
                                      onChanged: (bool newValue) {},
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          ),
```

Comment: What is the structure of checklists that you have from secoes?

Comment: "checklists": [
                {
                    "id": "28",
                    "idlicenca": "0000",
                    "idsecao": "5",
                    "quesito": "Adequados e não seguidos",
                    "status": "Ativo",
                    "excluido": "nao",
                    "logusuario": "-47",
                    "logdata": "2021-09-09 21:38:13",
                    "secao": "Procedimentos"
                },
               
            ]

Comment: Did you try to do  `title: Text(e.quesito),` in the SwitchListTile? If you parsed the data, that should show it.

Comment: Thanks! perfect, I was letting go of the fact that I already got a parsed

Comment: I will leave the answer below to be able to help the others in case they need it. Feel free to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you have the data parsed, you can simply call the data from the map.

```
...snapshot.data!.secoes![i].checklists!
  .map<Widget>(
  (e) => SwitchListTile(
    title: Text(e.quesito),
    value: true,
    onChanged: (bool newValue) {},
  ),
),
```